# vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_common_header.php

Tags: php, caching, vqmod

I am receiving this error message:

[17-Mar-2017 10:22:14 America/Detroit] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/smarthea/public_html/ocart/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_common_header.php on line 50

Here is the end of my code in the vqcache PHP file:

```
$this->template = 'default/template/common/header.tpl';     }          
{   $this->render();        }

?>
```

Which syntax am I missing?

Comment: Use an IDE that can properly format and indent your code, and you'll notice you have a brace imbalance somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See you modification-file. You just missed line number. Just look into instructions in modificator and correct it.
This error usually appear when you're using several vQmod mofificators that used same file. In you case they modify /catalog/controller/common/header.php

Comment: If I sent you the file, would you be willing to scan it quick? I can't make sense of what I am missing...

Comment: Ok. But I think I'll need access to the server or at least several files to be sure that it's work

Comment: Yes; can we chat via email? I can pay you.

Comment: Ok, alexslipknot@europe.com

Comment: SOLVED; you are AWESOME!